# Telerik Drop Down list not selecting or working on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, production-environment

I have take a drop down list of **telerik** with **AutoPostBack="true"** working fine on local and a staging server but not working on Production server

**aspx page**

```
 <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="rdllNational" runat="server" style="background-color:Silver" AutoPostBack="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="rdllNational_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

**code behind**

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
                    {
                        BindDefault();

                       binddata(rdllNational.SelectedValue);
                    }

                }



 protected void rdllNational_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.DropDownListEventArgs e)
        {
            BindDefault(); //fetching from Database
            binddata(rdllNational.SelectedValue);
        }
```

Comment: Did shraddha accepted your friend request>

Answer (score 0):

I have had simular problems. Try using Fiddler and see what the actual error message is that is returned by the callback.

I have had problems with the RadCompressionModule throwing null references.
Also try to include the page name into the url:
http://url/default.aspx instead of http://url/

Hope this helps.